# как получить правильно title страницы?

Tags: php, mvc

Пишу проект, используя mvc структуру модель-контроллер-представление. Саму структуру написал с 0. Также добавил геолокацию и отсюда столкнулся с проблемой. Пишу сео модуль, все данные попадают в бд и в зависимости от страницы выводятся. Никак не могу понять, как сделать такое: Я добавляю в бд title:'купить {$category} в {$region} по низкой цене'. И в зависимости от категории и региона мне должен выводиться заголовок. Например: "купить велосипед в Москве по низкой цене." Сейчас естественно у меня выводится точно такой же заголовок как и в бд. Как правильно реализовать такую идею. Как это обрабатывать и получать? Если я не ошибаюсь можно написать шаблонизатор. Но все страницы у меня с расширением .php и если получать страницу через file_get_contents(header.php), затем делать замену на переменную и выводить header.php, то не будет работать php код в этом файле. Если я не ошибаюсь. Подскажите пожалуйста, как более грамотно это реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Более грамотно будет скачать готовый шаблонизатор. Но если вы принципиально хотите написать свой, то вот функции которые вам помогут: `ob_...` для перехвата вывода, `extract` для распаковки массива, `include` для подключения шаблона. Если хотите прям пошаговое руководство, то найдите у Дмитрия Елисеева соответствующее видео

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю для общего развития.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это MVC, то у вас как минимум есть контроллер, который отдаёт в рендер пачку данных. И скорее всего, где-то в этом контролере вы как-то определяете переменную `$title`. Вот там, где определяете `$title`, делайте подстановку. Саму строчку редварительно измените на `купить %s в %s по низкой цене`:

```
$title = sprintf($title_from_db, $category, $region);
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересное решение!

Comment: И всё же нормального шаблонизатора это не заменит. А если нам нужно вывести массив в таблицу. Каким образом будет выглядеть `sprintf` тогда?

Comment: для рабароты с массивами у пыхи 10050 функций.

Comment: в любом случае, даже если прикручивать какой-нить twig, не нарушая mvc, обработку данных кашерно осуществлять в контроллере. Шаблонизатор кормить только готовыми наборами. Я так думаю!©